# What does enclitic mean here?

Tags: ancient-greek, enclitic

What does enclitic mean in Learn to Read Greek, by Keller?

> In Attic Greek the word tis, ti may function either as an indefinite
> pronoun or as an indefinite adjective. Its forms are identical with
> those of the interrogative pronoun/adjective except that the
> indefinite pronoun/adjective is enclitic in all its forms.

[image]

I cant find its meaning in

> en·clit·ic [enˈklidik, inˈklidik] noun enclitic (noun) · enclitics
> (plural noun) a word pronounced with so little emphasis that it is
> shortened and forms part of the preceding word, e.g., n't in can't.
> Compare with proclitic
>
> enclitic (adjective) denoting or relating to an enclitic.
>
> Origin mid 17th century: via late Latin from Greek enklitikos, from
> enklinein ‘lean on’, from en- ‘in, on’ + klinein ‘to lean’.

Answer (score 8):

In the context of Greek, when we say a word is "[enclitic](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/goodell/proclitics-and-enclitics)" it means it has no inherent accent. Thus the indefinite pronoun is usually τις not τίς. However, [it apparently is not always enclitic.](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=tis)

In some circumstances, Greek enclitics add an accent to the preceding word, as described by Goodell.

Comment: Possible ambiguity: an enclitic word *can* have an accent, particularly (only?) in cases where there are more than one together.